# Include in table records with your correspondent days

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need help for put a records of classes in my table view, but I don't now how I can't make this

Well I need make this [image] (this is a UX prototype - days of the week are in portuguese: horario= time, segunda = monday, terça = tuesday, quarta = wednesday, quinta = thursday, sexta = friday )

I need take a values of a date and check if is monday or tuesday or anywhere week day and put in currently column iqual UX prototype but I don't now how a can do this.

Below is my code

Here is my mock data

```
"agenda-aulas":[
    {
      "Data": "2020-09-21",
      "Horarios": [
          {
              "Periodo": "1",
              "HorarioInicio": "2020-09-21T07:30:00-0300",
              "HorarioTermino": "2020-09-21T08:20:00-0300",
              "IdDisciplina": "396",
              "DescricaoDisciplina": "Arte (Artes Visuais)",
              "DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina": "Arte Vi.",
              "DescricaoTurno": "Manhã",
              "IdEstabelecimento": "43",
              "DescricaoEstabelecimento": "Colégio Correio Lima",
              "TipoSituacaoHorario": "Normal"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "Data": "2020-09-22",
      "Horarios": [
          {
              "Periodo": "3",
              "HorarioInicio": "2020-09-22T09:10:00-0300",
              "HorarioTermino": "2020-09-22T10:00:00-0300",
              "IdDisciplina": "3",
              "DescricaoDisciplina": "História",
              "DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina": "Hist",
              "DescricaoTurno": "Manhã",
              "IdEstabelecimento": "43",
              "DescricaoEstabelecimento": "Colégio Correio Lima",
              "TipoSituacaoHorario": "Normal"
          }
      ]
  },
```

My Interface

```
interface IHorarios {
  Periodo: string;
  HorarioInicio: string;
  HorarioTermino: string;
  IdDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoTurno: string;
  IdEstabelecimento: string;
  DescricaoEstabelecimento: string;
  TipoSituacaoHorario: string;
}
export interface IAgendaAulas {
  Data: string;
  Horarios: IHorarios[];
}
```

My Service

```
const getAgendaAulas = async (
  dataAula: string
): Promise<IAgendaAulas | undefined> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await Api().get<IAgendaAulas[]>(
      `/agenda-aulas?DataAula=${dataAula}`
    );
    if (data && data[0]) {
      return data[0];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Interface into TSX

```
interface IAgendasAulasProps {
  agendaDeAulas: IAgendaAulas[];
  dataAtualizada: string;
}
```

My Consts and my useEffect and table

```
export const TabelaHorariosAulas: React.FC<IAgendasAulasProps> = ({
  agendaDeAulas,
  dataAtualizada,
}) => {
const [aula, setAula] = useState<IAgendaAulas>();

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas(dataAtualizada).then((data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (data) {
        setAula(data);
      } else {
        setAula({Data:"", Horarios:[]});
      }
    });
  }, [dataAtualizada]);

<Grid container>
        <Grid item sm={12}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table stickyHeader>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Horário</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Segunda</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Terça</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Quarta</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Quinta</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Sexta</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>

              <TableBody>
                {aula?.Horarios.map((horario, indexAulas) => (
                  <>
                    <TableRow key={indexAulas}>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                      <TableCell></TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
         </TableContainer>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, I am pretty sure `horario.Periodo` represents the day of the week, I didn't understand what the values in the first column represent, I just put the `horario.HorarioInicio`.

#### Table

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

type DaysTableRowProps = {
    indexAulas: number,
    horario: Map<string, string>,
}

const DaysTableRow: FunctionComponent<DaysTableRowProps> = ({ horario, indexAulas }) => {
  const time = horario.get("HorarioInicio");
  const day = horario.get("Periodo");
  const data = horario.get("DescricaoDisciplina"); 
  return (
    <TableRow key={indexAulas}>
      <TableCell>{time}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{day === "1" ? data : "-"}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{day === "2" ? data : "-"}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{day === "3" ? data : "-"}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{day === "4" ? data : "-"}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{day === "5" ? data : "-"}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};


export const TabelaHorariosAulas: React.FC<IAgendasAulasProps> = ({
  agendaDeAulas,
  dataAtualizada,
}) => {
  const [aula, setAula] = useState<IAgendaAulas>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas(dataAtualizada).then((data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (data) {
        setAula(data);
      } else {
        setAula({Data:"", Horarios:[]});
      }
    });
  }, [dataAtualizada]);
  
  <Grid container>
    <Grid item sm={12}>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table stickyHeader>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Horário</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Segunda</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Terça</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Quarta</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Quinta</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Sexta</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
  
          <TableBody>
            {aula?.Horarios.map((horario: Map<string, string>, indexAulas: number) => (
              <DaysTableRow horario={horario} indexAulas={indexAulas} />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>;
};
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answear, just a one more thing in this part of code ```const DiasTableRow = ({ horario, indexAulas }) ``` get me this error Binding element 'horario' implicitly has an 'any' type. how a can solve this? a try put ```const DiasTableRow = ({ horario: string, indexAulas:number  })``` but don't work

Comment: horario is Map<string, string>, I just updated the answer to include that.

Comment: thanks for your help and time but ins this part of code ```{aula?.Horarios.map((horario: Map<string, string>, indexAulas: number) => ( <DaysTableRow horario={horario} indexAulas={indexAulas} />))}``` i have this problem i try many thigs but i don't know how i can't solve

Comment: Argument of type '(horario: Map<string, string>, indexAulas: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IHorarios, index: number, array: IHorarios[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'horario' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'IHorarios' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<string, string>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.

Comment: Maybe I could understand more if I saw the whole code not just parts, but I believe the logic is clear to you know now.